# C# Dictionary Extension method syntax

Tags: c#, dictionary, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension method for dictionaries to shorten the `TryGetValue` syntax.

This is the extension and the exact same logic in a normal method.

```
private static List<T> TryGet<T>(this Dictionary<int, List<T>> dict, int key) 
{
    return dict.TryGetValue(key, out var output) ? output : new List<T>();
}

private static List<T> TryGet<T>(Dictionary<int, List<T>> dict, int key) 
{
    return dict.TryGetValue(key, out var output) ? output : new List<T>();
}

var works = TryGet(MyDict, MyInt);
var doesntWork = MyDict.TryGet...
```

The code simply does not find the extension. I made triple sure that the dictionary is the same and of the right type.

I have the extension code in a file with other working extensions, so that's not the problem either.

Comment: Can we see the declaration of MyDict?

Comment: Maybe because it's `private`?

Comment: The method is private

Comment: As a side note, you could make your extension method more useful by making generic the type of the key: `public static List<V> TryGet<K,V>(this Dictionary<K, List<V>> dict, K key)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension methods needs to be accessible for the calling method and should be defined in a `static class`. In the OP, it is likely that it was defined in a non-static class

```
public static class Extensions
{
public static List<T> TryGet<T>(this Dictionary<int, List<T>> dict, int key) {
    return dict.TryGetValue(key, out var output) ? output : new List<T>();
 }
 }
```

Comment: They don't need to be public. They can be internal - or even private if you only need to use them within the same class. They just need to be accessible to the code calling them.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes that is true.  I should have used the word "accessible". Will correct it

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods must be accessible by the caller and in a static class.

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> TryGet<T>(this Dictionary<int, List<T>> dict, int key) {
        return dict.TryGetValue(key, out var output) ? output : new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, extension methods don't have to be public. They just need to be accessible to the calling code. For example, this compiles with no problems: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/054844d6b08093d6d76d2384a7377877